# Limit Concurrent Node js

Tags: node.js, express, load-testing

I want to handle the limit clients / concurrent that access my API.

I'm using Express Node JS and after testing using Load Test & Load I've get a conclusion that my API was not responding after 10000 concurrent access it and the memory was reach about 90%.

I've used http.Agent.maxSockets, http.globalAgent to limit sockets about 500 request at one time but turns out the request always passed above 500,

I've also used [limiter](https://github.com/ded/express-limiter) without using redis
here's my code

```
var limiter = require('express-limiter')(app)
limiter({
  path: '*',
  method: 'all',
  lookup: ['connection.remoteAddress'],
  // 500 requests per seconds
  total: 500,
  expire: 1000
});
```

but when i user Stress test it still reach the memory peak.
Any Help?

Edit:

another information,
I'm not using Nginx or AWS for Load Balancer

Comment: Which tool are you using for load testing?

Comment: @user3452275 I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest and https://loader.io/

Comment: did you solve this?